# Matlab: squeeze a region of a plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Considering the following data

```
plot([100+rand(20,1)*300;1600;100+rand(20,1)*300],'o')
set(gca,'ytick',[100 200 300 400 2000]);
ylim([100 2000])
```

It has a lot of points is a restrained region of (100,400). But only one data is taking the entire space. What I plan to do is to give an equal space to the following ranges:

```
(100,200), (200,300), (300,400), (400,2000)
```

So, the top space must be squeezed.

Is there any neat way in Matlab for that?

[image: matlab figure]

Comment: I guess that the neatest way is a log scale on the y axis.

Comment: @A_C, the problem with log scale is `101` and `150` are shown so close to each other